# DB2 translate function equivalent in H2 for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, db2, h2

I am using in-memory H2 for unit testing where as prod env is running on DB2. I have a requirement to remove non-alphanumeric characters @. from a field. 
I used REPLACE(TRANSLATE(BE.PARTY2_FIELD,'@.','  '), ' ','') which is working in in unit testing using H2 but failing when running in actual env which uses DB2.
I see the reason is TRANSLATE function syntax in H2 and DB2 are different.

**H2** - TRANSLATE ( value , searchString , replacementString)

**DB2** - TRANSLATE ( value , replacementString, searchString)

Is there any solution to it which can work in both H2 and DB2?

Comment: Why on earth do you use different database platforms for testing and production?

Comment: H2 in-memory db helps to select, insert records at runtime and a physical db would throw error if same insert record test case is executed multiple times. BTW it was not my decision :(

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I've been through the same problem as @Prasant and create na [issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1585) at [H2 github](https://github.com/h2database/h2database) and make a pullrequest so when we're using the H2 in DB2 mode the translate function change the order of parameters